# Alternate background color of rows in a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I need to alternate the color of the items in my `CheckedListBox` but "alternatingColors" is not a property of `CheckedListBox`.

How do I go about making the item's colors alternate?

Comment: Apply alternating CSS classes to each item.

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborated on the stack you are using.  Is this for WPF, Winforms, MVC, etc?

Comment: @GrantWinney ahh. Was thinking CheckBoxList duh!

Comment: Seems `DataGridView` with two columns `CheckBoxColumn` and `TextBoxColumn`, and `DataGridVIew.AlternatingRowDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green` will be more simple approach

Answer (score 4):

The `OnDrawItem` event is inaccessible by default, but if you derive a new control based on `CheckedListBox`, then you can override the base event.

```
public class MyCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    private SolidBrush primaryColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    private SolidBrush alternateColor = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen);

    [Browsable(true)]
    public Color PrimaryColor
    {
        get { return primaryColor.Color; }
        set { primaryColor.Color = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public Color AlternateColor
    {
        get { return alternateColor.Color; }
        set { alternateColor.Color = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);

        if (Items.Count <= 0)
            return;

        var contentRect = e.Bounds;
        contentRect.X = 16;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(e.Index%2 == 0 ? primaryColor : alternateColor, contentRect);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(Items[e.Index]), e.Font, Brushes.Black, contentRect);
    }
}
```

It'll alternate between white and green by default. Make adjustments in the Properties panel at design time, or during runtime.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. So once i create a class and add this form, how do i put MyCheckedListBox onto my windows form? i can't just drag it from the toolbox

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is even possible. You may want to consider using a different control for what you need. A DataGridView might be able to work for you better.

Comment: yeah that would be dope